# ブロックを渡す gsub を委譲したとき、$1 が参照できなくなる理由はなんでしょうか？

Tags: ruby

Rails の SafeBuffer に ブロック付きの gsub を呼び、`$1` を参照したところ、nil でした。
同じ gsub を String で使うと、`$1` には値が入ります。

SafeBuffer のソースを見ると、`to_str` した後に、`gsub` を呼んでいましたので、
該当部分を取り出し、同じ挙動を再現しました(コードは末尾にあります)。

主要部分は下記です。

```
  def gsub(*args, &block)
    to_str.gsub(*args, &block)
  end
```

メソッドの中で、to_str してから gsub を呼ぶことで挙動が変わる理由はなんでしょうか？

$1 が [これらの変数はローカルスコープかつスレッドローカル](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Kernel/v/1.html)とあるため、
この現象はスコープが異なる、ということなのでしょうか？
その場合、レシーバーはどこですか？

コード
aタグ の text を抜き出すコードです

```
HREF_RE = /<a[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/ix

def pick_url(text)
  text.gsub(HREF_RE) do |a_tag|
    $1
  end
end

class StringWrapper < String
  def gsub(*args, &block)
    to_str.gsub(*args, &block)
  end
end

require 'minitest/unit'
require 'minitest/autorun'
class ATest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @url = 'http://example.com'
    @html = "<a href='#{@url}'>#{@url}</a>"
    @wrapped = StringWrapper.new(@html)
  end

  def test_gsub
    assert_equal @url, pick_url(@html)
  end

  def test_wrapped_gsub
    assert_equal @url, pick_url(@wrapped)
  end

  def test_wrapped_to_str_gsub
    assert_equal @url, pick_url(@wrapped.to_str)
  end
end
```

結果は下記になります。

```
  1) Failure:
ATest#test_wrapped_gsub [gsub_text_01.rb:30]:
Expected: "http://example.com"
  Actual: ""

3 runs, 3 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

追記 2015-07-20

参考資料
- [How to fix gsub on SafeBuffer objects - makandropedia](http://makandracards.com/makandra/11171-how-to-fix-gsub-on-safebuffer-objects)
- [gsub_file with block, no access to $1 etc? · Issue #207 · erikhuda/thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/issues/207)
- [ruby - Using $1, $2, etc. global variables inside method definition - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550434/using-1-2-etc-global-variables-inside-method-definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問のなかですでに答えは出ています。

挙動が変わる理由は`$1`がローカルスコープだからです。
今回の場合は、`String#gsub`を呼び出した関数内でのみ`$1`を参照できます。

```
def gsub(*args, &block)
  to_str.gsub(*args, &block)
  # $1のスコープ
end
```